Cannot make program when using sensehat libsense library
I currently have a raspberry pi hooked up to a sense HAT and I installed this sensehat library so I could do stuff with my sense HAT in cpp rather than python. Unfortunately I am encountering a problem whenever I use this library. The following code has worked before
Before, I would go into the terminal, make build compile and run all inside of the terminal (can't remember the compiler that it used) becauase I was never able to run it normally in vscode but now that i resolved that issue and started used g++, this started happening (g++ runs normally without these new libraries) .
*IDE I'm using is Vscode
Code used in this example:
#include <iostream>
#include <sensehat.h>
#include <console_io.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using string = std::string;


int main() {
    if (senseInit()) {
        //Create 3 vars
        double sensitivity = 0.2;
        double x, y, z;
        double xBefore, yBefore, zBefore;
        senseGetAccelG(xBefore, yBefore, zBefore);

        int touchies = -1;
        while (true) {
            usleep(50000);
            //Directly Modifies xyz values. Returns bool
            xBefore = x;
            yBefore = y;
            zBefore = z;
            if (senseGetAccelG(x,y,z)) {
                if (x - xBefore >= sensitivity || y - yBefore >= sensitivity || z - zBefore >= sensitivity) {
                    std::cout << "DETECTED!!!! DONT TOUCH!!!!! STTOOOPP" << std::endl;
                
                    touchies++;
                    senseShowMessage("NO TOUCH");
                }
                else { std::cout << "NO MOVEMENT / Touches: " + std::to_string(touchies) + "\n" << std::endl; }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "senseGetAccelG has failed" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        
    }  
    else {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong initating sense hat" << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;
}



Results of when I try to build and compile:
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch.cpp -o /home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o: in function `main':
/home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch.cpp:10: undefined reference to `senseInit()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch.cpp:15: undefined reference to `senseGetAccelG(double&, double&, double&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch.cpp:24: undefined reference to `senseGetAccelG(double&, double&, double&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fatblabs/projects/java/dontTouch.cpp:29: undefined reference to `senseShowMessage(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o:/usr/local/include/sensehat.h:140: undefined reference to `senseGetRGBpixel(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o:/usr/local/include/sensehat.h:158: undefined reference to `senseSetRGBpixel(int, int, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o:/usr/local/include/sensehat.h:170: undefined reference to `senseGetRGBpixels()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o:/usr/local/include/sensehat.h:189: undefined reference to `senseSetRGBpixels(rgb_pixels_t)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccyHJQdC.o:/usr/local/include/sensehat.h:219: undefined reference to `senseShowRGBColoredLetter(char, rgb_pixel_t, rgb_pixel_t)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

Results of when I try to make the file:
fatblabs@raspberrypi:~/projects/java $ make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicated-branches -Wsign-conversion -Wlogical-op -Wuseless-cast -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu++2a -o client client.cpp -lsensehat-c++ -lpng -li2c -lm -lRTIMULib -lgpiod
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:14: client] Error 1

Library I'm trying to use:
https://github.com/platu/libsensehat-cpp
I have tried looking at other solutions but have not completely matched with my problem.
This one may be a solution but I need some help with clarification (I'm unsure of how to link the library in vscode)
How to link libs in netbeans (linux)?

Looks like VS code wasn't told to link in the required third party libraries. There many code-building plug ins for VS Code you could be using, so you'll have to edit the question and tell us which one to write answers for. All I can say about the second build output is  client.cpp must not have a main. Make sure you saved the file.

It worked when i put a main method in client.cpp. But that's so weird why couldn't vscode find the libaries before?
